# Shared memory across go routines

Tags: go, concurrency, shared-memory, goroutine

The following test in Go fails:

```
type A struct {
    b bool
}

func TestWG(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    a := update(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
    if !a.b {
       t.Errorf("error")
    }
}

// Does not work
func update(group *sync.WaitGroup) A {
    a := A{
        b : false,
    }
    group.Add(1)
    go func() {
        a.b = true
        group.Done()
    }()
    return a
}
```

Initially I thought this is might be happening due to the absence of barrier in `waitGroup.Done()`, which might explain why changing `update` to

```
// works
func update(group *sync.WaitGroup) A {
    a := A{
        b : false,
    }
    group.Add(1)
    go func() {
        a.b = true
        group.Done()
    }()
    time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
    return a
}
```

works. But then changing return type to `pointer` also makes it work

```
// works
func update(group *sync.WaitGroup) *A {
    a := A{
        b : false,
    }
    group.Add(1)
    go func() {
        a.b = true
        group.Done()
    }()
    return &a
}
```

Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example has a data race!

You return `a` which needs to read it, and a concurrent goroutine (which you just launched) writes it without synchronization. So the output is undefined! `go test -race` also confirms this.

Same thing goes when you add a sleep: the data race remains ([`time.Sleep()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) is **not** a synchronization tool), so the result is still undefined! `go test -race` confirms this again.

When you change the return type to pointer, then you just return a pointer to `a` which does not involve reading the value of `a`, and the launched goroutine does not modify the pointer, just the pointed value. And the caller `TestWG()` properly waits until its done using the waitgroup, so no data race occurs here.

Comment: Why is it a data race if I am reading the value only after wg.Wait()?

Comment: @user3301880 That's it: returning `a` involves reading it, which happens before `wg.Wait()` is called, it happens concurrently with the other goroutine updating it. But when you return `&a`, that doesn't involve reading `a`.

Comment: That helps. Thank you so much.